# How to prove $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{n}{k-i}\binom{n+i-1}{i}=0$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I saw a combinatorial identity when i study linear-algebra, But the author  didn't explain how to get it.

> $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{n}{k-i}\binom{n+i-1}{i}=0$

Who can help me to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be convenient if you please elaborate on the assignment of the variables. Is i is of complex number?

Comment: oh ,no.i is also natural number as n,k.

Comment: oh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to require $k > 0$, as otherwise your claim is $1 = 0$.

Renaming $k$, $n$ and $i$ as $n$, $x$ and $k$, you get a particular case (the case $x=y$) of the following identity:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(-1\right)^k \dbinom{x}{n-k} \dbinom{k+y-1}{k} = \dbinom{x-y}{n}$.

This is, e.g., Proposition 3.32 **(d)** in my [*Notes on the combinatorial
fundamentals of algebra*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf). (In case of changing numbering, search for " some sample applications of Theorem", or check out the [frozen version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10), in which the numbering surely has not shifted.) The main trick to the proof is realizing that $\left(-1\right)^k \dbinom{k+y-1}{k}$ can be rewritten as $\dbinom{-y}{k}$, after which you are left with a particular case of the Vandermonde convolution identity.

Comment: Pretty good book！but seems a little  difficult to me ... I' ll try my best to read  it ! Thank you very much !

Comment: ok~thanks a lot!

Comment: This isn't a book, though it might become one... The proof of Proposition 2.25 is mostly self-contained, relying only on Theorem 2.24 and on some basic identities such as upper negation (Proposition 2.16). If you have trouble with the notations (such as binomial coefficients $\dbinom{m}{n}$ with negative $m$), look them up at the beginning of Chapter 2.